# Current UTC time in correct format with different system settings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in Excel which uses the current UTC time (hours and minutes) as a string that at the end will be (among other things) written as text in a new Word document.
Currently it works fine on my computer but it will be used on different computers as well that potentially have a different system setting for the datetime format. As none of these settings can be changed nor do I have a full view of all different ones, I need a part in my macro that will always give me the same format at the end.
The format I need to achieve is HHMM (in 24 hours, not AM/PM), example: 1430.
The code I have right now does this if the system time is in this format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS". Unfortunately it doesn't account for others such as "DD/MM/YYYY H:MM".
Is there an easy way to fix this?
The code I have right now is below. I found this code online and I am not good enough at VBA to understand the first part of it and adapt it to what I need.

```
Public Sub UTCtime()

Dim dt As Object, utc As Date, utcHOUR As String

Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    dt.SetVarDate Now
    utc = dt.GetVarDate(False)
    utcHOUR = utc
    utcHOUR = Replace(utcHOUR, ":", "")
    utcHOUR = Replace(utcHOUR, " ", "")
    utcHOUR = Right(utcHOUR, 6)
    utcHOUR = Left(utcHOUR, 4)
    utcHOUR = utcHOUR + "Z"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dt.GetVarDate()` returns a `Date` type adjusted to UTC, this is format agnostic (until coerced to a string) so simply:

```
strUTCTime = Format$(utc, "HHMM") & "Z"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, that's exactly what I needed!